# Работа с таймером в Qt. Помогите исправить баги

Tags: c++, qt

Задача:

Нужно, чтобы строка в текстовом поле плавно (каждую секунду) перемещалась вниз, а затем вверх по текстовому полю на то количество строк, которое установлено в `QSpinBox`,когда запущен `QCheckBox`.

То есть, если в `QSpinBox` установлено значение 5, то каждую секунду текст должен опускаеться на одну строку в течение пяти секунд, а затем так же плавно возвращаться в изначальное положение. Вот мой код

```
 #include <QtGui>
 #include "mainclass.h"
 #include <QTextCodec>
 #include <QHBoxLayout>
 #include <QVBoxLayout>

 MainClass::MainClass(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent){

QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("cp1251"));
QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("cp1251"));
QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("cp1251"));


tEdit = new QTextEdit (this);
tEdit -> resize (300, 300);
tEdit -> setText("Строка перемещается по полю");

timer = new QTimer (this);

QHBoxLayout *HLay = new QHBoxLayout (this);
QGroupBox *SG = new QGroupBox (this);
QVBoxLayout *VLay = new QVBoxLayout;

RunChBox = new QCheckBox (this);
RunChBox ->setText("Запуск");
rawsSpin = new QSpinBox (this);
rawsSpin->setRange(0, 6);
rawsSpin->setSingleStep(1);

VLay -> addWidget(RunChBox);
VLay -> addWidget(rawsSpin);
this ->setLayout(HLay);
SG ->setGeometry(300,0,100,100);
SG->setLayout(VLay);
timer->setInterval(1000);
connect (RunChBox,SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), SLOT(CheckBoxChecked()));
connect (rawsSpin,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), SLOT(CheckBoxChecked()));
connect (timer, SIGNAL (timeout()), SLOT(CheckBoxChecked()));

}

MainClass::~MainClass(){

}

void MainClass::CheckBoxChecked(){

  int ValueofSpin = rawsSpin->value();

 if (RunChBox->isChecked()){
  timer->start();

      for(int i = 0; i<ValueofSpin; i++){
         int V=rawsSpin->value();
          --V;
          QString str = "\n"+tEdit->toPlainText();
          tEdit -> setText(str);
          if (V==0){
              for (int j = 0; j<ValueofSpin; j++){
                  timer->start();
                  QString str = tEdit->toPlainText();
                  QStringList str2 = str.split('\r\n');
                  QString res =str2.at(0);
                  tEdit ->setText(res);
          }

          }
      }

  }
  else {
      timer->stop();
  }
}
```

Вроде бы цикл написан правильно, но программа делает не то что нужно, а именно:

1) Считывает значение из `QSpinBox` и перемещает строку вниз на это значение (Если в `QCheckBox` установлено, например, 5, то строка опускается вниз на 5 строк сразу каждую секунду, а должна по одной строке в течение пяти секунд)

2) Первый цикл `for` выполняется бесконечно, пока запущен `QCheckBox`, до второго цикла дело не доходит, хотя в коде есть условия `i < ValueofSpin`и `j < ValueofSpin`. Я добавляю значние `i++` и `j++`, то есть присутствует и коррекция, а значит ни один из циклов `for` не должен быть бесконеяным.

Почему так происходит? Как исправить эти ошибки?

Comment: У вас какая-то чушь написана. Первое, что надо понять - пока идет выполнение какого-то метода в основном потоке, гуй не будет отвечать. Поэтому все, написанное вами в в `CheckBoxChecked` в анимации вы не увидите, только результат всех действий.

Comment: @BeardedBeaver А в чем чушь?